# If statement doesn't work in shiny server.R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am using shiny to plot different time series of precipitation and temperature.

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Parametres"),

  plotOutput(outputId = "main_plot", height="500px"),

  hr(),

  fluidRow(
    column(4,
       selectInput(inputId = "Cellule",label = "Cellule:",choices = c(17,1404,2478,2792,3842,6103,7714,8442,8642),selected = 7714),
       selectInput(inputId = "Variable",label = "Variable:",choices = c("Ptot", "TEMP"),selected = "Ptot")
    ),
  )
))
```

Here is a part of my code for server.R, which doesn't work:

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, p. = p) {

output$main_plot <- renderPlot({  

....

if(input$Variable =="TEMP")
{
  Obs_inter$value <- Obs_inter$value-273.15
  Sim25_inter$value <- Sim25_inter$value-273.15
  Sim_1_inter$value <- Sim_1_inter$value-273.15
  Sim_2_inter$value <- Sim_2_inter$value-273.15

  ymin <- min(Obs_inter$value, Sim25_inter$value, Sim_1_inter$value, Sim_2_inter$value)
  ytitle <- "TEMP (°C)"
} else {
  if(input$Variable=="Ptot")
  {
    ymin <- 0
    ytitle <- "Ptot (mm)"
  }
}

p <- ggplot()

....

})

})
```

With Obs, Sim25, Sim_1 and Sim_2 my time series.

When I run my code, this is the error I get:

```
"Cannot find ymin"
```

So the loop with the if statement doesn't work. I tried to select ymin=0 before (no if statement) and I have what I want. What I do not understand is that I have another if statement before (not with input$Variable but another input) and it works.

I tried to print input$Variable to see what it returns but I don't know how to do that..

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try and make a minimal example that illustrates the problem - we can't run your edited code because bits are missing and at a glance I'm guessing the problem is in the missing bits...

Comment: `if (!(input$Variable %in% c("TEMP", "Ptot")))` this code doesn't create `ymin`.

Comment: @Roland your glance is better than mine! But can that happen with the controller given?

Comment: @Spacedman Don't know. I'm not a shiny user. If only two inputs are possible the second `if` is superfluous and can be removed savely. If not, a second `else` is needed. But in that case, the nested `if` should be rewritten to `switch`. If nothing else it would improve clarity of code

Comment: Agreed. Plus I can't get the code to work as-is even with removing any reference of the dataset and trying to simplify the structure. Giving up.